# GitLab - dont wait for all jobs in the previous stage to be finished

Tags: azure-devops, gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

In my pipeline, the two last stages are Deploy and Qa-test. It look like this:
[image: pipeline now]

Now I need to run integration-tests automatically when the deploy-stag job is finished and not to wait for deploy-prod.

Is there some way to do this?

Comment: just add/trigger test stage after deploy stage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [needs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#needs) to create an direct acyclic graph. If your `integration-tests` job needs the `deploy-stag` job, it will immediately start after `deploy-stag` is finished and will not wait for the remaining jobs in the deploy stage.

```
integration-tests:
  stage: qa-tests
  script:
    - echo "running qa tests"
  needs: ["deploy-stag"]
```

Comment: This looks good. Can I use 'needs' with rules?

Comment: @Urago yes you can

Comment: Now iam getting this error: undefined need: deploy-stag   ... I have yml file for this job at different folder. Could this be why iam gettting this error?